# dc.js Tutorial Line Chart Render

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, dc.js

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697043/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-2-Graphing) on the JavaScript library dc.js and am having an issue with rendering a line chart in the tutorial. I get something to [display](http://unc.edu/~shafferk/dc_test.html), but it doesn't look at all the way it should in the tutorial. The D3 and Crossfilter parts of the code seem to be talking to each other since the brushing functionality works, so I'm wondering if I don't have the CSS referenced correctly. You can easily view the code by just viewing the page source. I'm assuming this is something simple that I'm just overlooking due to being fairly new to CSS and JavaScript. Thanks in advance for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the fill attribute on the path svg element is not set, so it's defaulting to black, giving you that black fill in the middle. When I open the developer console in my browser (using IE), I get error messages that say "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch." for both dc.css and colorbrewer.css. GitHub is a pain with mime types, so you may want to move these files elsewhere.

The work-around to get the fill to go away (but not addressing your css loading problem) is adding this line of code:

```
 d3.select(".line").attr("fill-opacity", 0);
```

I hope that helps!